# Why is the alignment of the swt (Labels) component destroyed?

Tags: java, swt, rcp

This is one RCP Eclipse APP, 
you have a LIST of an Object (name, quantity, image), it is downloaded with a FOR loop.

This information is downloaded and each attribute of the object is displayed in the APP with a Label each one.

for example:

```
lblName[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, getObject().getName(), 8); 
lblName[idx].setBounds(5, pos, 195, 20);

lblValue[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, getObject().getValue(), 8); 
lblValue[idx].setBounds(205, pos, 73, 20);

lblStatus[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, "", 8);
lblStatus[idx].setBounds(280, pos, 39, 20);
 lblStatus[idx].setImage(StateIconManager.getImageForState(getObject().getImg()));
```

This aligns these three attributes and is displayed: [Name] [Quantity] [Image]

This works, the problem here is: After a running time the APP, it is misaligned like this:

[image]

Some idea so that the Labels stay always aligned?

Comment: Impossible to say from these bits of code. If the dialog/form/... is using SWT Layouts the `setBounds` calls will be overriden by the layout.

Comment: There is something that can be done here, so that it does not overflow again, but that it stays aligned?

Comment: You have not shown us enough code to know what is going on. Show us a proper [mcve].

Comment: Each frame (4 Composite), where the Labels will be displayed, will receive:

- Composite group = new Composite(this, SWT.BORDER);

- compGroup[0][1] = new GetComposite(group, SWT.BORDER, 3, 320, 120);  

- public GetComposite(Composite parent, int style, int numOfColumns, int width, int height) { super(parent, style);
  this.setLayout(new GridLayout(numOfColumns, false));
  this.setLayoutData(new GridData(width,height)); } 


lblName[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, getObject().getName(), 8); 
lblName[idx].setBounds(5, pos, 195, 20);

However, they do not stay stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using a `GridLayout` for the `Composite` containing these conrols. You **cannot** uses `setBounds` in a `Composite` that is being managed by a layout. The layout will override your bounds with the bounds that it calculates.

Since you are using `GridLayout` you should set `GridData` layout data on each of your controls. `GridData` has many fields which let you control the positioning and size of the cntrol.